# Get actual Job Name of the running SSIS package from Program Name column of the results while running sp_whoisactive or sp_who2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, sp-whoisactive

When I run `sp_whoisactive` or `sp_who2` and if there is a SSIS Package running it would always display in the Program Name as the name of the running SSIS Package like `SSIS-Package-{063BC46B-1F74-4207-A263-4F78A705RAE4}ServerName.dbname.dw`.

Instead of it I want the name of the SQL Agent Job which is running.

Since I offload the data for monitoring I want the SQL Job name to be displayed instead of the Package Name.

Can any one help me with it.

Comment: Is the SSIS package running from the same server it's connecting to?  In our environment, SSIS runs on it's own server so all we see is the connection by the SSIS package itself, no way to get the agent job name.  If you are all running on the same server, then there should be another line in sp_whoisactive for the job as well.

Comment: It runs from the same server. I have checked by running  dbo.sp_WhoIsActive   @get_additional_info = 1 and I don't see the name of the job in the additional info column .